# Customize calendar function in angularMoment

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I would like to use customized output for calendar in angularMoment.

In momentjs I set it up with:

```
moment.lang('en', {
calendar : {
    lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
    sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
    nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
    lastWeek : 'ddd, LT',
    nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
    sameElse : function () { 
        if (this < moment().startOf('year'))
            return 'M/D/YY';
        else
            return 'ddd, MMM D';
    }
}
});
```

In angular, I tried the following (and a few variations) with no luck:

```
angular.module('main').constant('angularMomentConfig', {
lang: 'en'
, {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
        sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
        lastWeek : 'ddd, LT',
        nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
        sameElse : function () { 
            if (moment() < moment().startOf('year'))
                return 'M/D/YY';
            else
                return 'ddd, MMM D';
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you don't need to do anything different!  I used the `moment.lang` definition without change and it works fine.

(Note: use `moment.locale` for more recent versions.)